# How to say this time 00:00 in words in English?

Tags: time

How should I say this time: **00:00** in words?

For example if someone asks me about the exact time and I would like to answer him exactly what I see in my watch [00:00 or 00:01]. Let's suppose that I want to use in 24-hour system for my answer, Then what I should say correctly here?

> "It is_____?"

The same question about **00:01**.

I always refer to it as twelve, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

Comment: I have heard "zero hours" before. You can check the voice announcements on [*WWV (radio station)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWV_(radio_station)) or similar time standard services to hear the format they use.

Comment: @user3169  I think that's military slang, e.g. [*Zero Dark Thirty*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oh_dark_thirty) which means "some unspecified time in the early morning".  There are probably a lot of nuanced meanings that vary with context.

Comment: @Andrew It would be better if the OP added some contextual/locale information.

Comment: Edited. context added.

Answer (score 3):

> [**midnight**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/midnight) (n): *the middle of the night; specifically : 12 o'clock at night*

*00:01* would be "one minute after/past midnight".

Aside from the military and a few other services, most of the United States uses the 12-hour clock instead of the 24-hour clock.  So we would say:

> twelve midnight

and

> twelve-oh-one in the morning

Comment: For "00:00" you can also say "twelve midnight" and "twelve AM".  For "12:01" you could also say "one minute after midnight".

Comment: I've spelled out 12:01 to explain what actual words you would say, there may be some regional variation (twelve zero one?)

Comment: Then if I want to use 24-hour-system, the answer **in numbers** is necessary to be from 12-hour-system? Can I say for example "It is Oh, oh, oh, oh" [for 00:00] or It is "oh oh oh one" [for 00:01]?

Comment: In addition, I think when you say it is **midnight**, for most people is not accurate time but it is approximate, like around 00:00 plus minus. Isn't it?

Comment: @Archimedean_Point  Sure, just like anywhere else in the world.  Unless what you're doing requires precision, no one really cares if you're off by a few minutes.